# Vertical align inside table-row

Tags: html, css

How to align vertically content inside #container which has a display of table-row;?

_#content may have inline or block element or even a child with fixed height. It just need to be aligned vertically no matter how.

The bottom div should always be at the bottom of the screen and the height of the top div should be equal to the remaining height.

```
<div id="container">
    <span>content</span>
    <div>content</div>
</div>
<div id="wrap">
    <img src="http://www.boylesoftware.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/280x250_css3_logo.jpg" height="100">
</div>    

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "bonvenocf";
    height: 100%;
    background: #ccc;
    max-height: 1080px;
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 1080px;
}

#wrap {
    text-align:center;  
    background: #1b1b1b;
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}

#container {
    width: 100%;
    background: #0084ff;
    height:100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```

This is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4tvjvwpk/3/

Comment: `table-row`? I don;t see that in your code.

Comment: Sorry check my updated question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`vertical-align` is only applicable to inline-level and table-cell elements.

Hence you could add a div and change its display type to `table-cell` and add `vertical-align: middle` to the element as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/4tvjvwpk/5/)**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="cell">
        <span>content</span>
        <div>content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.cell {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I can not because it breaks my layout. The bottom div should always be at the bottom of the screen and the height of the top div should be equal to the remaining height.

Comment: @rexhin refined the answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have content in a `table-row`.  Instead, make it a `table-cell`. But maybe you should look into `Flexbox` for creating what you are looking for.

Reference: [**CSS Tricks**](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: I can not because it breaks my layout. The bottom div should always be at the bottom of the screen and the height of the top div should be equal to the remaining height.